# Comparing Deep Nested Array of Array of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of array of hashes which can be nested any level deep.

```
array = [
    [ ['a','2'],  ['b','5'] ], 
    [ ['c','4'], ['d','5']  ],  
    [ ['e','6'], [f,7] ],
    ...]
```

In the first stage I need to compare each consecutive hash - keep one of the elements and discarding the other.
In the second step the selected element of hash 1 have to be compared to selected element of the hash 2. This process has to continue till i am left with just one hashed element.

How do i do this i Ruby ?

thanks a lot for answering

Comment: Those aren't hashes, those are arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for.  Can you please explain in more detail what you want, including the expected output as well as the expected input?  Your "first stage" is especially in need of more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `==`:

```
array1 = [
    [ ['a','2'],  ['b','5'] ], 
    [ ['c','4'], ['d','5']  ],  
    [ ['e','6'], ['f',7] ]
    ]
array2 = [
    [ ['a','2'],  ['b','5'] ], 
    [ ['c','4'], ['d','5']  ],  
    [ ['e','6'], ['f',7] ]
    ]
array3 = [
    [ ['not','equal'] ]
    ]

array1 == array2
# => true

array2 == array3
# => false
```

See [`Array#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D) for specifics.